# Is there a way to find the URL of a Skype meeting that you were “kicked out” of but never received an invite for?

Tags: skype-for-business

Note: the term “kicked out” here refers to being kicked out of the meeting due to some technical problem (e.g. loss of network connectivity, Skype crash, and so on).

**Update:** When this happens sometimes the entire meeting window disappears and no "Rejoin" button is presented to the user. This question is for these cases when the "Rejoin" button is missing.

**Note:** This question is also about a specific subset of Skype for Business meetings. In this case, meetings attended in a scenario where the user was pulled to the meeting directly (meaning user did not receive e.g. Calendar invite with a link to the meeting).

In this scenario, is there a way to find the URL of the Skype meeting that the user was kicked out of?

Comment: Don't you get somewhere the message of "You've left the call" with a "Rejoin" button?

Comment: @harrymc thank you for your comment. I have seen that "Rejoin" button when I leave a Skype meeting on my own, but there have been a handful of cases (we use Skype quite a lot at my employer) where I have gotten kicked out so completely that Skype does not show that button. So with this question I wanted to find out about other ways to determine what the meeting URL is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Skype chat commands list](http://kosi2801.freepgs.com/2008/12/20/skype_chat_commands.html) mentions this command :

> /get uri - Skype 4: Gets the URI link for this public chat which can
>   then be sent to contacts or embedded in webpages.

Not using Skype, I cannot test if this command is what you want,
or whether it must only be entered before the disconnection.

For more qualified answers, you could post the question in the
[Skype Community](http://community.skype.com/?category.id=English).

Comment: Even if it's before disconnection, it would at least provide the information in case it's needed.